# C# и .NET. Какой метод будет менее ресурсозатратный и какой будет быстрее выполняться?

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый день! Я новичок в .NET и я задался вопросом (вопрос чисто на интерес и не имеет никакой практической цели):
Какой из методов для вывода массива лучше использовать:

1. Который будет в цикле на каждый элемент вызывать метод `Console.Write($"{element} ")`
2. Который будет использовать класс `StringBuilder` и вызывать в цикле на каждой итерации метод `Append(element)` и `Append(' ')` и в конце вызовет 1 метод Console.WriteLine();

**P.S.** Проблемы с созданием списка в вопросе. Вроде как делаю все по инструкции, а список не создается.

**UPD.** Методы, про которые я говорю:

Метод 1

```
private static void PrintArray<T>(T[] Array)
    {
        foreach (T item in Array)
        {
            Console.Write($"{item} ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Метод 2

```
    private static void PrintArray<T>(T[] Array)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (T item in Array)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(item);
            stringBuilder.Append(' ');
        }

        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: +1 за слово "новичок" через два "о" :)

Comment: @Igor От описки никто не застрахован :) Скажите, а как Вы список отобразили? из-за чего у меня не создавался список?

Comment: пустые строчки перед началом списка и между пунктами

Comment: @Igor Спасибо!) Надеюсь, больше не буду раздражать людей своим плохо отформатированным вопросом)

Comment: Вариант со StringBuilder будет быстрее для ValueType потому что интерполяция будет использовать боксинг. Для ссылочных типов разницы быть не должно. Вывод в консоль довольно медленный сам по себе, поэтому вывод одной большой строки, будет быстрее вывода той же строки по частям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм... Со StringBuilder получается 36 МС, а без него 523 МС.

Вот код для тестирования:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int len = 1000; //Размер массива
        string[] arr = new string[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = "blablablabla";
        }
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int counter = 0;
        var stopWatch1 = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch1.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length ; i++)
        {
            if (counter>=100|| i== arr.Length - 1) //Пуляем по 100 элементов в консоль
            {
                Console.Write(strBuilder.ToString());
                strBuilder.Clear();
                counter = 0;
            }
            counter++;
            strBuilder.Append("\n" + arr[i]);
        }
        stopWatch1.Stop();
        var stopWatch2 = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch2.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
        stopWatch2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"StringBuilder MS={stopWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Без StringBuilder MS={stopWatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Однако, не стоит пытаться все подряд оптимизировать и оптимизацией следует заниматься только в том случае, если это критическая точка программы.

Есть знаменитая фраза:

> Преждевременная оптимизация — корень всех зол

---

В комментария меня поправили и на самом деле автору хотелось выводить строку не порциями, как я тестировал, а агрегировать ее в StringBuilder, а потом за один раз вывести.

В этом случае первый цикл будет таким:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length ; i++)
            {
                strBuilder.Append("\n" + arr[i]);
            }
Console.Write(strBuilder.ToString());
```

В итоге скорость на 1000 элемента изменилась с 36 МС до ~20 МС.

Но нужно иметь в виду, что консоль не бесконечная и если я не ошибаюсь, то одновременно в них может находится ~8000 символов => пытаясь вывести за раз большее количество, мы теряем часть информации => вывод порциями более правильный.

Так же побочный эффект этого подхода в том, что объединенный массив где-то нужно хранить=> большие расходы на память, если массив здоровенный.

Разница во времени с использованием StringBuilder и без его использования я думаю, что можно объяснить тем, что операция IO сама по себе медленная=> чем реже мы обращаемся к консоли, тем быстрее работает все в целом.

Comment: Извините, но я не совсем то имел ввиду. Вы вызываете `Сonsole.Write()` много раз со `StringBuilder`, а я говорил про 1 раз.
Если это правдивые результаты теста, то это очень странно. Еще хотелось бы узнать, почему результаты так сильно отличаются. Я сейчас добавлю методы в вопрос, про которые я говорил.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, Я добавил еще 1 тест.

Comment: Так у Вас в первом тесте выполнение операций IO в цикле со `StringBuilder` столько же, сколько и в цикле без него (во втором). Если это так, тогда это вряд ли связано с медленными операциями IO. Или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko *"Еще хотелось бы узнать, почему результаты так сильно отличаются"* -- запись в консоль -- это IO. IO = медленно. `StringBuilder` -- это RAM. RAM = быстро.

Comment: @iluxa1810 для более объективных результатов перед замером нужно делать прогрев, потом собирать мусор, а потом замерять в нескольких итерациях и усреднять. И все в релизе, конечно же.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, если расматривать мой самый первый тест, где я порциями отправляю данные в консоль, то там вместо 1000 обращений к консоли, я делаю всего 10.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Все, теперь я понял. Я if - условие не до конца прочитал. Спасибо!

Comment: @andreycha Насколько сильно данные действия влияют на результат теста на время? какая погрешность будет, если этого не сделать?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko код вам уже написали, поэкспериментируйте :).